# Basis dimension (k) too low for the smooth term in a GAMM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv, gamm4

I am running a generalized additive model (GAM), but when I check the model diagnostics  (using `gam.check()`) I run into problems. I have tried adjusting the value of `k`, but this isn't working. **What am I missing?**

Note that `gam.check()` lets you see if the number of basis functions (`k`) is appropriate (as per this [OP](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302203/laymans-explanation-of-basis-dimension-k-in-generalized-additive-models-gams)). In my case, it shows that it is significant. I tried different values of `k` to see what value of `k` would give me a non-significant p-value, but it is always significant. **Does this mean that the `k` is appropriate or is there a different test to see if the `k` value is appropriate for the smoothing term?**

I'm using `R`, version 3.6.1; `mgcv` version 1.8-34; `gamm4` version 0.2-6.

The data (called `prime`) I used is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

Here is how my data frame is currently structured (first 6 rows):

```
ID       DaysBeforeMigration  AdultMass  OffspringMass
A00001   59                   59.52239   57.18145
A00002   61                   143.8808   61.75128
A00002   63                   147.7373   68.80916
A00002   61                   143.8808   41.82444
A00002   63                   147.7373   61.4211
A00002   61                   143.8808   61.64883
```

Here is the code and packages to run my generalized additive model:

```
require(mgcv)
require(gamm4)
prime <- read.csv("MyData.csv”)
mod1 <- gamm4(OffspringMass ~ DaysBeforeMigration + s(AdultMass, 
            k=9), random=~(1|ID), data=prime)
```

Output:

```
> summary(mod1$gam) 
Family: gaussian
Link function: identity

Formula:
OffspringMass ~ DaysBeforeMigration + s(AdultMass, k = 9)
 
Parametric coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)         53.73208    3.88430  13.833   <2e-16 ***
DaysBeforeMigration  0.09548    0.07662   1.246    0.215   
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
               edf Ref.df     F p-value   
s(AdultMass) 1.935  1.935 13.86 5.8e-06 ***
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 
R-sq.(adj) =  0.231  
lmer.REML = 830.06  Scale est. = 63.323    n = 109
```

Diagnostic output:

```
> gam.check(mod1$gam)
 
'gamm' based fit - care required with interpretation.
Checks based on working residuals may be misleading.
Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.
 
               k'  edf k-index p-value  
s(AdultMass) 8.00 1.94    0.77   0.005 **
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Diagnostic figure code:

```
plot.gam(mod1$gam, residuals = TRUE, pch =1, cex = 1, shade = 
         TRUE, shade.col = "lightblue", seWithMean = TRUE, 
         pages = 1, all.terms = TRUE)
```

The diagnostic figures:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a huge problem in your case.

The best I can find on it is p.330-331 of [this guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JP9XunsZUqucMf6nFY1vbgt0ueNrqWuu/view?usp=sharing) by Simon Wood.

Because the `edf` is way below the basis dimension I don't see it as a problem (quote from Wood on page 331: "*The...test still gives a low p-value, but since the `edf` is...below the basis dimension, and increasing the basis dimension barely changes the fitted values,...stick with `k=100`...*").

So, fitting more basis functions by setting higher `k` would not make much logical sense given the size of the data set.

The book also talks about finding the best `k`, but in the case of your data allowing the default seems fine as the model will converge to a straight line (`edf = 1`).